# Javascript fake db running on github

Tags: javascript, database, github, jwt, github-actions

I would like to create a fake db in `javascript` that runs on `Github`.

I am thinking of using `axios-mock-adapter`, I figured out how to set it up but I don't know how to make it work.

That is, how should I create the environment around it to make it work, if possible on `Github`.

At the moment I managed to create the following structure:

mock.js

```
const MockAdapter = require('axios-mock-adapter');
const axios = require('axios');

const mock = new MockAdapter(axios, { delayResponse: 0 });
export default mock;
```

index.js

```
import './db/auth-db';
import mock from './mock';

mock.onAny().passThrough();
```

./db/auth-db.js

```
import _ from '@lodash';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import mock from '../mock';
/* eslint-disable camelcase */

const jwtConfig = {
    secret: 'some-secret-code-goes-here',
    expiresIn: '2 days' // A numeric value is interpreted as a seconds count. If you use a string be sure you provide the time units (days, hours, etc)
};

const authDB = {
    users: [
        {
            uuid: '08b6bf4161024491b71c397c36d8eb7d',
            password: 'admin',
            role: 'admin',
      email: 'leo@gmail.com',
            data: {
                displayName: 'Leonardo DiCaprio',
                photoURL: 'https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Leonardo_Dicaprio_Cannes_2019_2.jpg'
            }
        },
        {
            uuid: '77e83a5c0f414883b1655079491c278d',
            password: 'staff',
            role: 'staff',
      email: 'depp@gmail.com',
            data: {
                displayName: 'Johnny Depp',
                photoURL: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/79/Johnny_Depp_Deauville_2019.jpg/440px-Johnny_Depp_Deauville_2019.jpg'
        }
    ]
};

mock.onGet('/api/auth').reply(config => {
    const data = JSON.parse(config.data);
    const { email, password } = data;

    const user = _.cloneDeep(authDB.users.find(_user => _user.email === email));

    const error = {
        email: user ? null : 'Check your username/email',
        password: user && user.password === password ? null : 'Check your password'
    };

    if (!error.email && !error.password && !error.displayName) {
        delete user.password;

        const access_token = jwt.sign({ id: user.uuid }, jwtConfig.secret, { expiresIn: jwtConfig.expiresIn });

        const response = {
            user,
            access_token
        };

        return [200, response];
    }
    return [200, { error }];
});
```

Comment: Github is a source code management website, why would you want to do that? Besides, you cannot host a proper database in github, the best you can do is host webpages there using github pages, but then again, they are static web pages, only your browser js would be able to access it for one session. 

Even if you were to use github actions, they time out in a few hours and I doubt you can connect to it.

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar, OP is trying to automate tests using GitHub Workflows. And no, I've used MongoDB to automate my database tests. The timeout shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Alright, then the question would require some corrections, this is quite misleading. Yes, you are correct, if you are running some tests on them, they probably won't time out too soon.